# vb2008 search through listbox using textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox, listbox

hi I have a form that find, or should I say filter, the items in a listbox using a textbox. I have a textbox used for searching and a listbox populated with items from database. Now, say listbox items include apple, banana, berry, cashew, lemon, mango, peanut. If I typed 'b' on the textbox, listbox only show banana and berry..if I typed 'ba' then listbox only show banana but if I typed 'be' then it shows berry and so on. I already got this working (with the code marked as commented in the txtSearch event). My problem is that how can I bring the items in the listbox back when the user strike the backspace? Because, say I have banana and berry in the listbox now, when I erased the text that I typed in the textbox it should list back all the items again so that if I want to search another item it will be filtered again. thanks in advance.

**Code Update**

```
Public Class Glossary

Private Sub Glossary_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call List()
    Refreshlist()
End Sub
Private Sub List()
    Dim myCmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader
    Dim myAdptr As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim myDataTable As New DataTable
    Call Connect()
    With Me
        STRSQL = "Select word from glossary"
        Try
            myCmd.Connection = myConn
            myCmd.CommandText = STRSQL
            myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader
            If (myReader.Read()) Then
                myReader.Close()
                myAdptr.SelectCommand = myCmd
                myAdptr.Fill(myDataTable)
                lstword.DisplayMember = "word"
                lstword.ValueMember = "word"
                If myDataTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    For i As Integer = 0 To myDataTable.Rows.Count - 1
                        lstword.Items.Add(myDataTable.Rows(i)("word"))
                    Next
                End If
            End If
            'lstword.Items.Clear()
            'lstword.Items.AddRange(word.Where(Function(word) word.ToString().Contains(txtSearch.Text)).ToArray())
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
        myReader = Nothing
        myCmd = Nothing
        myConn.Close()
        Call Disconnect()
    End With
End Sub

Dim word As List(Of Object)
Private Sub Refreshlist()
    lstword.Items.Clear()
    lstword.Items.AddRange(word.Where(Function(word) word.ToString().Contains(txtSearch.Text)).ToArray())
End Sub
Private Sub txtSearch_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtSearch.TextChanged
    lstword.Items.Clear()
    lstword.Items.AddRange(word.Where(Function(word) word.ToString().Contains(txtSearch.Text)).ToArray())
    Refreshlist()
    'Call List()
    'lstword.BeginUpdate()

    'Try
    '    ' keep track of the "non-searched items" '
    '    Dim word As New List(Of Object)

    '    lstword.SelectedIndices.Clear()
    '    If txtSearch.Text.Length > 0 Then
    '        For index As Integer = 0 To lstword.Items.Count - 1
    '            Dim item As String = lstword.Items(index).ToString()

    '            If item.IndexOf(txtSearch.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 Then
    '                lstword.SelectedIndices.Add(index)
    '            Else
    '                ' this item was not searched for; we will remove it '
    '                word.Add(index)
    '            End If
    '        Next

    '        ' go backwards to avoid problems with indices being shifted '
    '        For i As Integer = word.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    '            Dim indexToRemove As Integer = word(i)
    '            lstword.Items.RemoveAt(indexToRemove)
    '        Next
    '    End If
    'Finally
    '    lstword.EndUpdate()
    'End Try

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: @Steven Doggart: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' and 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source' - I got that error sir, but when I removed the `Refreshlist()` in the load event. I already followed your corrections below but this errors occured :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to store the items in off-screen memory.  For instance:

```
Dim words As List(Of Object)
```

Then when you refresh the list box, only populate it with the items from that in-memory list which match the current criteria:

```
lstword.Items.Clear()
lstword.Items.AddRange(
    words.FindAll(
        Function(word) Return word.ToString().Contains(txtSearch.Text)
        ).ToArray()
    )
```

Or, using LINQ:

```
lstword.Items.Clear()
lstword.Items.AddRange(
    words.Where(
        Function(word) word.ToString().Contains(txtSearch.Text)
        ).ToArray()
    )
```

**UPDATE**

Since you seem to be having trouble getting it working, and it's hard to say what's wrong with your code without actually seeing it, here's a complete working example:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim words As New List(Of Object)(New String() {"apple", "banana", "berry", "cashew", "lemon", "mango", "peanut"})

    Private Sub RefreshList()
        lstword.Items.Clear()
        lstword.Items.AddRange(
            words.Where(
                Function(word) word.ToString().Contains(txtSearch.Text)
                ).ToArray()
            )
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtSearch_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSearch.TextChanged
        RefreshList()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        RefreshList()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**UPDATE 2**

I tried using your code with my recommended suggestions and it worked fine.  Here's the code that worked for me.  Try it and let me know if it doesn't work for you:

```
Public Class Glossary
    Private Sub Glossary_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        List()
        Refreshlist()
    End Sub

    Private Sub List()
        word.AddRange(New String() {"apple", "banana", "berry", "cashew", "lemon", "mango", "peanut"})
    End Sub

    Private word As New List(Of Object)()

    Private Sub Refreshlist()
        lstword.Items.Clear()
        lstword.Items.AddRange(word.Where(Function(word) word.ToString().Contains(txtSearch.Text)).ToArray())
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtSearch_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtSearch.TextChanged
        Refreshlist()
    End Sub
End Class
```

If that works, then all you need to do is change the `List` method to load from the database instead of being a hard-coded list.

Comment: I'm sorry sir I didn't get that easily, d'you mean I should write `Dim words As List(Of Object)` inside the class of the form only? Then the next code should be placed inside the lstword method, or I should make a function for it? (I'm really, really sorry sir, I'm not familiar with the terms and I have just learned a little about this subject.Please forgive me).

Comment: Yes, I would say that you would most likely want the `words` variable to be declared at the class/form level, inside the form class, but outside of any method.  Variables declared at that scope are called *fields*.  You should make it `Private` too, rather than using `Dim`, which makes fields `Public` by default.  The block of code that populates the list box would be good to put in its own method.  I'd call the method `RefreshList` or something like that.  Presumably you'll need to call it from more than one place (from load and text change), so it makes sense to make it a separate method.

Comment: I appreciate your kindness sir, really :), but I got another solution regarding my problem in the previous. I already updated my question above, please take a look at it sir.

Comment: Well, obviously, if you remove the items from the list box, and you don't keep them in a separate object in memory, as I recommended, then there is no way to get the removed items back (short of re-querying the database, that is).  It's precisely because of this short-coming that you have encountered that I recommended doing it the way I did.  The only way to get back items that were previously removed is to keep the full list somewhere in memory.  That's why both Tony and I both recommended keeping the full list in a `List` object.

Comment: oh..yeah i used your code above for the LINQ sir and didn't use my code above anymore. I placed the `words` inside the class only and used the LINQ code inside the `txtSearch_textChanged` event but when I started typing in the textbox I got error 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source'..I also tried using my code above and place the LINQ code before lstWord.BeginUpdate but got the same error, then I tried to put the code inside the load event but got the same error before the form loads. I'm now confused sir, what should I do? :(

Comment: the `New String()` part..those items that I gave above was just an example of the items. I have items stored in the database so I cannot list the items there what the listbox will contain. I updated my code above sir, that's the whole program for what I'm doing..the same error is appearing :(

Comment: Your first problem is that you never set the `words` variable to a new object.  To fix that, change `Dim word As List(Of Object)` to `Private word As List(Of Object)`.  The second problem is that you never populate the `word` list.  To fix that, change the line `lstword.Items.Add(myDataTable.Rows(i)("word"))` to `word.Add(myDataTable.Rows(i)("word"))`.  Also, in the `txtSearch_TextChanged` method, just call `RefreshList`.  Don't do anything else in there.

Comment: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' and 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source' - I got that error sir, but when I removed the Refreshlist() in the load event. I already followed your corrections below but this errors occured :(

Comment: Did you try my complete example form?  I realize that it doesn't get the data from the database, but it shows in principle how to do it.  It works for me, so I'm curious to know if it works for you.

Comment: I added another update to my answer.  Please try that and let me know how it goes.

Comment: oh my God!! I can't believe I didn't get this earlier, I was almost there. How stupid can I get >.<..thank you very, very much sir, you're such my life saver, this is not only the time you saved me, I owe you a lot sir :D..sorry for being a headache, God bless you more sir :D

Answer (score 0):

Get your initial list off the database, pop it in a List class e.g List.
The use your search text to select all the matching items and put them in the list box. Blank search text you just put all of them in.

You might want to have a look at Foreach and List.FindAll as well.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, can you please give an example sir?

Comment: Looks like Steven Doggart is doing that. My example would be in C Sharp and I doubt you need that at the moment. Hadn't realised how new this was to you either. This is actually Intermediate stuff, and I'm not sure you've picked up novice yet. Best way to use us, is have a go, read the books and tutorials and then when you get stuck ask for help. We could just give you the code, but you'd learn very little just by pasting it in to your app.

Comment: yeah..I'm just beginning to learn VB so this intermediate stuff is still new to me. I'm not a good programmer but I'm trying to be one so forgive me if I sometimes I can't pick up the idea easily. I'm already doing what you said sir, thanks again :)

Comment: Programming is a thing you can only learn by doing, you are making a good start. At least you know you don't know how to do it, far too many don't...

Comment: As afoot note despite my start at it being 1976, I'm still learning, and have no plans to stop.